# Unable to generate desired PDF template with FPDF in Core PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

[image: Current Result]

This should not overlap it should wrap the text.

I need to design the template the possible scenarios are.

1. sometimes it is possible that date has more rows then the response (Case shown in picutre)
2. sometimes response has more rows then the date.

My current code:

```
$data = $this->getExportData($survey_id, $question_id);
            
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);

// Add header with survey name
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, $survey_name, 0, 1, 'C');

// Add table with survey results
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
$pdf->SetFillColor(242, 242, 242);
$pdf->Cell(80, 10, 'Time', 1, 0, 'C', true);
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'Response', 1, 1, 'C', true);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);

// Add data
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $pdf->Cell(80, 10, $row['Date'], 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->WordWrap($text,80);
    $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $row['Response'], 1, 1, 'L');
    $pdf->WordWrap($text,0);
}
// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: When you post question with data, it's very easy for someone to help you if you post `$data` as array, so we could help you much easier.

Comment: The script [Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3) can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `MultiCell`:

```
$data = $this->getExportData($survey_id, $question_id);

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);

// Add header with survey name
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, $survey_name, 0, 1, 'C');

// Add table with survey results
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
$pdf->SetFillColor(242, 242, 242);
$pdf->Cell(80, 10, 'Time', 1, 0, 'C', true);
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'Response', 1, 1, 'C', true);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);

// Add data
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $date = $row['Date'];
    $response = $row['Response'];
    $dateLines = $pdf->getNumLines($date, 80);
    $responseLines = $pdf->getNumLines($response, $pdf->GetPageWidth() - 80);
    $maxLines = max($dateLines, $responseLines);
    $pdf->MultiCell(80, $maxLines * 10, $date, 1, 'C');
    $pdf->MultiCell(0, $maxLines * 10, $response, 1, 'L');
}

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$pdf->Output();
```